# Why doesn't IDE BlueJ give me an error for invalid `main()` declaration?

Tags: java, bluej

In my college, I was taught Java using BlueJ and we were asked to write `main()` in the following manner (no string array present as parameter):

```
public static void main()
{
//code
}
```

This works in BlueJ but it doesn't work in other IDEs like Eclipse (using right now).

All over the internet and books (except college texts), I find `main()` declared as 
`public static void main(String[] args)` .

My doubts:

- When is the first way of declaring `main()` valid?
- If the first declaration is wrong, why isn't BlueJ giving an error?
- Is BlueJ designed to handle this internally?
- What is the actual use of the string array parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why main() method is needed in java main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443459/why-main-method-is-needed-in-java-main-class)

Comment: Your college is wrong. The actual signature is `public static void main(String[] args)`. The args array contain the command line arguments passed to your application. You should not use BlueJ, use IntelliJ or Eclipse (welcome to 2016).

Comment: Is there a particular reason for why BlueJ is supporting the wrong syntax?

Comment: You never noticed that BlueJ doesn't need a user defined 'main' method? And since it doesn't, why should it care about inproper signatures of the 'main' method?

Comment: @sturcotte06:  In BlueJ's defense, it's a good beginner's IDE and doesn't immediately overwhelm the user.

Comment: @Tom I read in one of the answers in link pasted by PM 77-1 that string array argumeng is required for the command line to pass info. Then how are the programs running without this requirement being satisfied?

Comment: To clarify: the code you posted isn't invalid, it's just not a "real" `main` function. An IDE is allowed to give you more ways to run a piece of code, essentially be generating its own `main(String[])` and having it invoke the code you want to run. A lot of IDEs do that with unit test frameworks, for instance.

Comment: @yshavit Now that makes sense.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Now I wonder why you think that this isn't satisfied. Never thought about that BlueJ defines the 'main' method, so the user doesn't need to do that? This is one of the features of this IDE for beginners.

Comment: @Tom Thanks a lot. Got it now. would you mind converting that comment to an answer so that I could accept it and close the question?

Comment: my guess is that BlueJ has its own legitimate main() or whatever that turns around and calls this bastardized main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueJ does not require THE main method we all know aka `public static void main(String[] args) { }` so BlueJ is seeing that as a regular static method that happens to be called `main` "coincidentally."