# I am running java code and my while loop file is not running in VS Code Studio, other programs are running but, I got stuck here in the while loop

Tags: java

This is the image before I run code:

[image]

And this is the image after running the code:

[image]

Please help me.

I was expecting the code to be running but, it throws error.

Comment: Your while loop needs to be in a method.

Comment: And PLEASE, never give code as images.  It makes it impossible for people to try out your code to find out what's going wrong.  And other reasons, as described by Mr President in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `static void main()` for your program to start:

```
public class print1_10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter < 11) {
            System.out.println(counter);
            counter++;
        }
    }

}
```

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7443459/2330053) for more information...

Comment: If you think the answers to that other question also serve to answer THIS question, then you should vote to close this question as a duplicate, instead of answering it.

Comment: I think that other question has a lot of information, but none of them show a complete class with a `main()` in it, so I posted one here.

Comment: Sure.  I was looking for an accurate duplicate question myself, because it seems to me that this particular question gets asked quite often.  I didn't manage to find one, which suggests that it typically gets closed and deleted when someone asks it.  Good point about clearly showing a `main()`.  Here, have an upvote.

Comment: yes this is the correct answer for the question , you have to put your logic code inside 
 the main method or create a separate method and call in main method